# Ideals of $ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose there is some positive integer $k \neq 1$ such that $k^2\mid n$.

Can I prove that there exists two distinct ideals $I $ and $J$ of $ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} $ such that $I $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/ k\mathbb{Z}$ and $J $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/k^2\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

(1) Show that $\;I\;$ is an ideal of the ring $\;\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\;$ iff $\;I\;$ is a subgroup of the additive group of this ring.

(2) A cyclic finite group of order $\;n\;$ has *one unique* subgroup of order $\;d\;$, when $\;d\;$ is any divisor of $\;n\;$ .

Comment: Does the same hold if I replace ideals (in the question) with submodules over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If you take the ring itself to be *the* module then yes.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall~n\in\mathbb Z^+,~\phi:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_n:z+n\mathbb{Z}\mapsto z~(mod~n)$ is a ring isomorphism. So try to deal with $\mathbb Z_n.$

In fact, show for $\langle k\rangle=\{x\times_nk:x\in\mathbb{Z}_n\}$ and $\langle k^2\rangle=\{x\times_nk^2:x\in\mathbb{Z}_n\}$ $$\phi_1:\mathbb Z_k\to\langle k\rangle:z\mapsto z\times\dfrac{n}{ k}\\\phi_2:\mathbb Z_{k^2}\to\langle k^2\rangle:z\mapsto z\times\dfrac{n}{ k^2}$$ are ring isomorphisms.

Comment: I don't understand: what's **for you** the difference between $\;\Bbb Zn\Bbb Z\;$ and $\;\Bbb Z_n\;$ ??

Comment: None to an algebrist's eye. That's what I demostrated through isomorphism.

Comment: I think this is wrong, @Sugata. You just defined the identity map between identical sets (and algebraic structures) without making this clear. To write "is a ring homomorphism" can misldead someone new in this to think those two objects are different whereas they are identical...at least until, much later, $\;p-$adic numbers and stuff are studied.